# What is the average battery life of an NES cartridge?

Tags: nes

How many years does an NES cartridge battery last?

Comment: What? You mean they are battery driven and loose all savegames when the battery dies? Oo Does that only affect the savegames or will it make the whole game unplayable?

Comment: @Dave: Only save games

Comment: Someone oughtta figure out a way to replace/recharge those, otherwise my collection is going to devalue seriously right before they become serious collectors items :-p

Comment: @Mechko: they've been replacing them for years: http://www.the9thkey.com/games/Nesbatt.htm

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.the9thkey.com/games/Nesbatt.htm), the batteries last 15-20 years.

Comment: may come in handy one day

Comment: Wow. Truly impressive quality, considering 5-10 years wouldn't have hurt their sales in the slightest.

Comment: While batteries do eventually die, only save games are affected by a dead battery. At least that's the way it works on my gemfire game.